# Service Fabric, which certificate do I use where?

Tags: azure, https, ssl-certificate, azure-service-fabric

I'm settings up a Service Fabric cluster in Azure and want to run a web API (using .NET Core) over https. I want to use my CA-signed wildcard (*.mydomain.com) certificate to access this API. But I'm a bit confused as to where I use it when I create the cluster, is it the cluster or client certificate? I'm thinking the client certificate, but the documentation states that this is for admin tools (i.e. the Explorer), so I'm unsure on how to proceed.

And yes I've read a ton of posts and resources, but I still find this confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three certificate types.  Here is a summary overview of them.

The **Cluster certificate** is used for the Explorer endpoint and is deployed to the primary nodes.  So if you add your `*.mydomain.com` wildcard cert there, and CNAME something (e.g. `manage.mydomain.com`) to `[yourcluster].[region].cloudapp.azure.com`, then when you hit your management endpoint that cert will be what will be presented to the web browser.

The **Reverse Proxy SSL certificate** is deployed to each of the nodes and is used when using the built-in reverse proxy feature of Service Fabric.  In this case this is what is being used when you hit `https://api.mydomain.com/YourAppName/YourService/Resource` (where `api.mydomain.com` is another CNAME to `yourcluster.region.cloudapp.azure.com`).  This is used as an alternative to running your own reverse proxy or other offloading layer (Application Gateway, IIS, nginx, API Management, etc).

The **Client certificates** are used in place of Azure Active Directory authentication to the management endpoint.  So instead of managing users in AAD (with the `_Cluster` AAD application and the Admin / Read-Only roles), you manage access by handing out management certificates (Admin or Read-Only) to your trusted users.

You can also have secondaries these certificates to use in certificate rollover situations.

Comment: Looks like this is the correct solution. I've tried setting it up, but the nodes won't join the cluster. I think there's some small error in the ARM template.

Answer (score 1):

The way we are using it is to have Application gateway configured in front of service fabric cluster, and web certificate is uploaded to Application Gateway (and dns is pointing to application gateway) In that scenario SSL is terminated at application gateway.

Another possibility is to terminate SSL at each node in service fabric cluster, in this scenario you would need to ensure that certificate gets deployed to each of the nodes.

As for cluster vs client certificate dilemma, I am also confused, but I think the answer is neither. Client certificate is not for sure since this certificate is used to identify you as admin when running service fabric admin ps scripts.

I do not think it is cluster certificate either, here is what MS docs say what it is used for:

*Cluster and server certificate is required to secure a cluster and prevent unauthorized access to it. It provides cluster security in two ways:
Cluster authentication: Authenticates node-to-node communication for cluster federation. Only nodes that can prove their identity with this certificate can join the cluster.
Server authentication: Authenticates the cluster management endpoints to a management client, so that the management client knows it is talking to the real cluster. This certificate also provides an SSL for the HTTPS management API and for Service Fabric Explorer over HTTPS.*

as far as I am reading into it, this certificate is used for internal cluster authentication, and it is also used so your management tools can be asured that they are working with right cluster.

Comment: I did think about using the Application gateway in front of the cluster, but I still have to expose the API, and as soon as I do that it's public to the outside world. Unless there is a way to secure the connection between the gateway and the cluster?

Comment: Getting the certificate to the nodes is the easy part, I just upload it to a key vault and include it in the osProfile of the ARM script. Then it's deployed automatically. I'm still just not sure which of the certificate types (client or cluster) we're dealing with here.

Comment: Yes I've also read this and was baffled because I expected to see something about securing the connections to the APIs. You might be right that I'd have to install the certificates manually on each node. This just seems so weird since it would go beyond the osProfile of the ARM template.